# Converting ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 for MultipartFormData in Play2 + Scala when parsing email from Sendgrid

Tags: scala, encoding, playframework, playframework-2.1, sendgrid

I have hooked up my Play2+Scala application to [Sendgrid Parse Api](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) and  I'm really struggling in decoding and encoding the content of the email.

Since the emails could be in different encodings Sendgrid provides us with a JSON object charsets:

```
{"to":"UTF-8","cc":"UTF-8","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8","text":"iso-8859-1","html":"iso-8859-1"}
```

In my test case `"text"` is `"Med Vänliga Hälsningar Jakobs Webshop"` 
If I extract that from the multipart request and print it out:

```
Logger.info(request.body.dataParts.get("text").get)
```

I get:

```
Med V?nliga H?lsningar Jakobs Webshop
```

Ok so with the given info from Sendgrid let's fix the string so that it is **UTF-8**.

```
def parseMail = Action(parse.multipartFormData) {
    request => {

    val inputBuffer = request.body.dataParts.get("text").map {
        v => ByteBuffer.wrap(v.head.getBytes())
    }

    val fromCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")
    val toCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")

    val data = fromCharset.decode(inputBuffer.get)
    Logger.info(""+data)

    val outputBuffer = toCharset.encode(data)
    val text = new String(outputBuffer.array())

    // Save stuff to MongoDB instance

}
```

This results in:

```
Med Vï¿½nliga Hï¿½lsningar Jakobs Webshop
```

So this is very strange. This should work. 
I wonder what actually happens in the body parser  `parse.multipartFormData` and the datapart handler:

```
def handleDataPart: PartHandler[Part] = {
        case headers @ PartInfoMatcher(partName) if !FileInfoMatcher.unapply(headers).isDefined =>
          Traversable.takeUpTo[Array[Byte]](DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_LENGTH)
            .transform(Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().map(bytes => DataPart(partName, new String(bytes, "utf-8")))(play.core.Execution.internalContext))
            .flatMap { data =>
              Cont({
                case Input.El(_) => Done(MaxDataPartSizeExceeded(partName), Input.Empty)
                case in => Done(data, in)
              })
            }(play.core.Execution.internalContext)
      }
```

When consuming the data a new String is created with the encoding utf-8:

```
.transform(Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().map(bytes => DataPart(partName, new String(bytes, "utf-8")))(play.core.Execution.internalContext))
```

Does this mean that my **ISO-8859-1** encoded string **text** is encoded with utf-8 when parsed? If so, how should I create my parser to decode and then encode my params according to the provided JSON object charsets?
Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to copy the implementation of the parse.multipartFormData function, changing the decodings from `utf-8` to `iso-8859-1`, and use that in your Action.

The problem is that play decodes everything with `UTF-8` by default, and there is no way to change that, other than implementing your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the default encoding to UTF-8?

See this question for details: [Printing Unicode from Scala interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948044/printing-unicode-from-scala-interpreter)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer but no luck with the -D param