# scala default encoding in windows shell

Tags: scala, encoding

Beginners question: I'm using scala 2.11.4 on a windows 8 machine in the standard command shell (codepage is 850).
If I type "Müller" at the scala-prompt
scala>"Müller"
res0: String = M?ller

The same happens in my first scala trial program:

```
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

object Hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val myname=readLine("What is your name?","ISO-8859-1")
      println("Hallo " + myname + "!")
    }
}
```

Calling it via "scala Hello" yields:
What is your name?Müller
Hallo M?ller!

I guess println uses a different encoding as a default (The "ISO-8859-1"-part did not change anything, by the way)?

Comment: Did you tried with `UTF-8` encoding? I cannot test, but on Unix machine the default works as expected.

Comment: What does doing `chcp 1252` before firing up the scala repl do? I guess you don't have unicode codepoints enable on the cmd shell

Comment: The Scala repl just uses whatever encoding is available to it when it's fired up - that is to say, it inherits those properties from the existing environment.

Comment: chcp 65001 does not support äüö etc on german keyboard

Comment: @S.R.I in a way you're right: but it does not pick up the console default as I expected, uses java default settings (cp1252 in a windows environment) instead. But thank you, it lead to the right point!

Comment: See my answer for related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38490217/3706042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

showed `cp1252`.
So I generated a environment variable (thanx to Martin Sturm)
`JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=CP850"`
and currently everything works as expected (München ist schön).