# Scala vs. Groovy behavior when printing UTF-8 char in Windows terminal

Tags: windows, scala, groovy, encoding, utf-8

My question is similar to [Printing Unicode from Scala interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948044/1127485) and [scala default encoding in windows shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27671103/1127485), but goes into more detail WRT different behavior of Scala (version 2.12.2) vs. Groovy (version 2.4.7).

I have the following code snippet (which happens to be both valid Scala and Groovy code):

```
println("└─ ");
println("├─ ");
println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

When running the `scala` interpreter on it the Windows terminal (all of cmd, PowerShell, Git Bash / mintty) it shows

```
$ scala a.scala
??
??
Cp1252
```

However, running the exact same code through the `groovy` interpreter it shows:

```
$ groovy a.scala
└─
├─
Cp1252
```

My understanding from reading the answers to the linked questions is that the output is (solely) dependent on the value of the `file.encoding` system property. If so, how can the output be different between Scala and Groovy then if the used `file.encoding` is the same?

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23226994/1127485) seems to confirm it's an issue with the encoding used by the Scala compiler to read the source code file, which seems to default to whatever `file.encoding` is set to, even if the file clearly is UTF-8 encoded. I'm still wondering why Scala is not as smart as Groovy here...

**Edit 2:** I can work around the issue by running

```
$ scala -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 a.scala
└─
├─
UTF8
```

but still this dos not answer the question why Groovy does get it right despite `file.encoding` being set to `Cp1252`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's connected with different source encoding during compilation step

try this instead of `println("├─ ");`

```
println("\u251C\u2500");
```

or for `groovy` there is a parameter `--encoding` to specify the encoding of the source files.

quite sure for scala should be the same parameter

finally better not to use non-ASCII  characters in your source code.

I used [this service](http://itpro.cz/juniconv/) to convert chars (but any ide can do it for you)

Comment: Good idea that it's related to the encoding the compiler uses to read the file. However, your code still gives `??` for Scala for me, and now for Groovy too.

Comment: When reading through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23226994/1127485) it indeed seems you're right, but it's still awkward that Scala would use `file.encoding` even if the file clearly is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Ok, another point could be is `console encoding`. for me (on `windows`) if i set console encoding to `1252` with command `chcp 1252` then i'll see `??` in output. and if i choose `chcp 437` then i'll see `├─`.

Comment: and check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: Yeah, I've read that (or similar) answers, but these refer to the general console font, which cannot be the cause if it works with Groovy, but does not work with Scala in the same console window.

Comment: i just installed `scala 2.12.2` and i have `groovy 2.4.11` and your code executed fine in the same console with same output.