# How to convert a integer string to unicode string in scala?

Tags: string, scala, unicode

I need to convert any integers as strings to unicode strings. For example:

`"23"` to `"/u2082/u2083"`

Do you know a library doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome back Ewelina, and thank you for using "stack overflow". I am not too familiar with scala, however I have found another question that is similar to that of yours please refer to it and see if it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948044/printing-unicode-from-scala-interpreter

Comment: The example you've provided is, I think, impossible.  The unicode set U+208x is for digits to be rendered as subscript characters.  The string "23" contains no subscript/superscript information.

Answer (score 1):

All characters representing digits are already in the first 128 symbols of the ASCII table. And the first 128 ASCII symbols match the first 128 symbols of the Unicode encodings like UTF-8, 16 or 32.

You don't need to encode them.