# Spark-shell backspace is printing '$<3>' on screen

Tags: scala, spark-shell

I'm pretty new to scala & Spark and as I try to delete a line of code I see $<3> instead of deleting the desired line/character.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMjN1.png)

Comment: Take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948044/printing-unicode-from-scala-interpreter

Comment: thnx .. but I think this the case where a character is being replaced by another character. Don't think delete/erase will fall in this category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TERM=xterm-256color
then run the spark-shell and you should be good to go !